# How do I survive a Yeti outbreak?

Tags: achievements, revenge-of-the-titans

For the Revenge of the Titans achievement called Drunken Family Argument, you have to defeat masses of Yeti in the bonus map.

However, these rabid yeti are very devious and smart, avoiding any blocked off areas and ripping through your thinly distributed defenses.

What are some tricks you can use to get this achievement?

Comment: Yeti outbreak - hard to see that and not lol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm still trying to replicate [this user's strategy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LglnN_2VE_4&feature=youtu.be). It's fairly similar to [another video I tried to learn from](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=libBsa_Epso). The main concepts in his strategy seem to be this:

- Spam the hell out of the refineries, don't bother buffing them
- Find a narrow passage in the rock formations on the map where the mobs will have to move through and build your main defense line around that. I would go so far as to say if your map doesn't have anything like that, just start over until you randomly get a viable landscape.
- Use Scarecrows, spreader and brick walls to direct the mob flow into tight funnels and bounce them around
- Use droids for mobile brick wall protection

After finally beating it myself, here's what I took away as some additional pointers to win the thing:

- Build a chokepoint. It can be a total roadblock, just make sure sure the mobs are sufficiently slowed down while in your towers' range.
- Use tangleweb. It will help greatly to keep mobs confused while inside your towers' range.
- Use droids to wear down the enemy before it reaches your choke point. This will help significantly with the big yetis.
- Focus on heavy weaponry, skip blasters. Regular, heavy and multiblasters just won't cut it. Instead go with assault, spread cannons and lasers.
- Buff your towers for range, reload and firing speed. Batteries don't help that much in my opinion and reactors take up too much space.
- If you can afford it, draw an additional line behind your chokepoint, even if it is out of range most of the time to prevent a breakthrough.

The mission will take about 30 minutes in total, the big yetis appear roughly every 5 minutes. I found the smaller, faster guys towards the end the more challenging adversaries, as their armor is raised pretty high.

When things get icky, quickly draw a line of blockade in front of your towers. Always watch out for smartbomb powerups, they will be your best friend in the large waves towards the end. Good luck!

Comment: man, talk about hard achievements for those indie games.  The atom zombie smasher one was just as bad (once I got past the stupid BSOD)

Comment: Yeah, the AZS achievement took me a bunch of attempts, too. Nothing compared to this one, though.. After trying it in a few attempts I'm pretty sure blocking the yetis' path is not gonna work at all, their armor/hp is consistently rising and they get faster, too. Building them chokepoint of turrets and constantly protecting the front lines is the only strategy that even gets me close to completing the achievement. THere is however a [savegame floating around the steamforums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=27706789&postcount=17).. it's getting tempting. -_-

Comment: One thing that guy doesn't seem to do that helps a lot is building Tangleweb in the chokepoint; it's one of the few ways of slowing enemies down. Of course, that might be because he didn't have a very good choke; the enemies will sometimes path around it.

Comment: Agreed, I just managed to do it in a chokepoint with tangleweb and droids. Droids would have worn the big guys down when they reached the tangleweb, at which point spread and assault towers would finish the job. Finally.

Comment: so would you change anything from what your suggested in trying for the achievement or is that pretty much what you went with?  What type of guns should I focus on for defense?

Comment: I added my insight from last night to the answer. Even with all that insight, it's still a tough nut to crack. I do enjoy coming back to it and refine my strategy now, tho. Yay indie games!

Comment: ugh, I died after the 4th one. sigh

Comment: finally got the achievement.  The trick is to find a sideways choke point and line the bottom with attack towers.  That way you have a nice and long alley to kill the monsters in.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you spawn on a map with a tight chokepoint.

Use the delayed bombs at the beginning while you put down refineries. After using up the 5 limit, you should have enough for rockets and 1-2 batteries. Save up for a disruptor and put that by your rocket. Then put down 2 more batteries and 3-4 reloaders. Then save up for a laser. By the time the first boss comes out you should have your laser turret up near the upgrade buildings. Focus a bit more on upgrade buildings and then spam 3-4 reactors at the rear of your 3 turrets (laser has priority). Then build your tank factory in range of the reactors. Build whatever you want or think you will need after that.

Use lines of tanglewebs to slow titans down and layers of barricades in front of your turret line.

edit: Added a video jump to ~5 minutes in. http://www.twitch.tv/doodootoo/b/304090212

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this doesn't help you much but this game has a bug.

In one game the Yetis stopped and formed a line. Some time after that they died. Until the end of the game only a few Yetis had spawned and I killed them without problem.

So I guess there is some probability that in some game you will encounter the same buggy behavior, and complete the achievement without a problem.

Comment: This happened with me as well. I put scarecrows in a narrow passage, the AI didn't seem to know how to get around them. The Yetis stopped, then eventually died. Then all the other waves never even came on screen, I assume they just stopped as soon as the spawned because I could still hear them dying.